# Uninstalling IntenseDebate

Tags: plugins, uninstallation

I have been using the [IntenseDebate Comments plugin](http://www.intensedebate.com/features), but am unhappy with it and would like to uninstall. Supposedly due to the [data synchronization feature](http://support.intensedebate.com/wordpress-plugin/troubleshooting-wp/#data-synchronization), it shouldn't be a problem to just disable and remove it, but of course [there's nothing on their support site about how to uninstall](http://support.intensedebate.com/)...

Does anyone with experience removing it have survival tips for me?

Also, what will I *lose* in the process of uninstalling (e.g. Gravatar icons)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a place to find this out on there site http://intensedebate.com/faq#li58

Comment: Thanks, that link is the how-to. But the question of "what will it break?" remains on the table...

Comment: are you talking about the comments that are already there? If so then they should stay on the server as well. check your database in the comments table see if it is populated. Next thing is make a backup and then remove the comments plugin and see if they remain